# Magento how to set custom language in email Translator

Tags: magento

when send order or invoice email，the email content language is default localcode.

so i want to set custom language by one customer's attribute.

overwrite this model：

Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template

```
 public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $emails, $name, $vars = array(), $storeId = null) {
    $this -> setSentSuccess(false);
    // print_r($emails);die;
    foreach ((array)$emails as $key => $email) {
        if (($storeId === null) && $this -> getDesignConfig() -> getStore()) {
            $storeId = $this -> getDesignConfig() -> getStore();
        }

        if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
            $this -> load($templateId);
        } else {
            $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
            $webSiteId = array(Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId(),1);
            $webSiteId = array_unique($webSiteId);
            $Customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
            $Customer->setWebsiteId($webSiteId);
            $Customer->loadByEmail($email);
            $language = $Customer->getData('language');
            if (isset($language) && !empty($language)) {
                $localeCode = $this -> setLanguageByAsiointikieli($language);
            } else {
                $localeCode = 'en_US';
            }
            // Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocale($localeCode);
            // Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocaleCode($localeCode);
            $this -> loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
        }
        ....
```

now , i set custom language is en_US.default language is fi_FI.

The result is:

email content title is right(en_US).but email content value is wrong(fi_FI)，is not en_US.

As shown below:

click this
[order email image](http://blog.mallol.cn/order_email.jpg)

why?? Who can help me ??